# How to combine ng-bootstrap with regular bootstrap css?

Tags: ng-bootstrap

I am using some features of Boostrap 4 that are not supported or planned to be supported in ng-boostrap--namely a card layout.

I tried including the bootstrap .css per normal, but now a button group I am using loses its styling.  Can these coexist, and if so, how?

The top is using the normal styles: class="btn btn-light active".  The bottom is a straight cut-and-paste from the Button Group reactive sample on the ng-bootstrap site.  As you can see it is pretty mangled.

[image]

Comment: ng-bootstrap is *designed* to work with the standard bootstrap css. It doesn't replace the CSS part of bootstrap, only the JS part. A card layout doesn't need JS at all: it's pure html and bootstrap css, so there's no reason for ng-boostrap to do anything about it. Are you sure you're using the version of bootstrap that is required by ng-bootstrap? Which are the versions you're using?

Comment: Looks like it is a documentation error.  I had to add back in the "btn" to the class list.  https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons/examples

Answer (score 0):

Ok; got it all sorted:

1. As JB Nizet mentioned, you still need to include the .css.
2. I had included NgbModule in my root AppComponent,
   but not my other component.  That is why it wasn't working.  Once I
   made that change it all started working, including the what seemed like a missing class attribute.